# asp server controls get lost when added requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery 1.7.2 min.js plugin for my webpage and I found strange behavior after I add a requiredfieldvalidator all my server side control disappear even from page source after running it.
Below is the given code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mnmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/include_script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    $('.scroll-panel').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
<style>
.bx-controls{ display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div>
            <a href="index.html" class="logocont"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"/></a>          
            <div class="main-menu">
            <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="malaga.html" id="idTestLink">PROJECTS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-project">
            <li><a href="#">Ongoing Projects</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="malaga.html">Malaga</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="lastP">Titanium</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="career.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <div id="lavalamp"></div>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    

<div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto; padding:0px; position:relative; height:84%; background:url(images/malaga/bg.jpg);"> 
<div class="career_left">
        <ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img src="images/career.jpg" title="intro" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="career_right">
        <div class="career-details">
            <h2>careers</h2>
            <div class="scroll-panel jspScrollable">
                <h5 style="padding:0 0 10px 0">Interested candidates who wish to further their career prospects can e-mail their resumes to careers@groupcodevelopers.com or fill in the below form and submit.</h5>

                <div>
                <form runat="server" class="career-form">
                        <div style="margin-top:0;">
                            <label>Name </label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" class="career-textfield" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z \n\r.]+/g, '');" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="gpcareer"
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="please enter your name" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Email Id </label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailId" class="career-textfield" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="gpcareer"
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="please enter Email Id" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId"
                                runat="server" Display="None" ValidationGroup="gpcareer" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email."
                                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*|EMAIL"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Mobile </label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" class="career-textfield" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,'');"/>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ValidationGroup="gpcareer"
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="please enter Contact Number" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtMobile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress" class="career-textarea"></asp:TextBox>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ValidationGroup="gpcareer"
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Address" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtAddress"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Resume</label>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="txtResume" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="txtResume" ValidationGroup="gpcareer" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Attach Your Resume."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgResume" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txtResume" runat="server" Display="None" ValidationGroup="gpcareer"  ErrorMessage="Invalid Resume File." ValidationExpression="(.*?)\.(doc|docx|pdf|rtf|)$">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom:0;">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" class="button_wh" ValidationGroup="gpcareer" Text="SUBMIT"/>
                             <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="gpcareer" ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"
                            ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
                        </div>
                </form></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div style=" overflow:hidden; padding:11px 50px; z-index:999">
    <div class="footer-left">
        <p class="ml15">Groupco © 2014 | Privacy Policy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right">
        <p class="ml15">Conquest Media House</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem in above code is when I remove either requiredfieldvalidator or jquery1.7.2 plugin controls become visible. But it disappear even from page source when this plugin or validator is added. The error it throw in firebug is :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'controltovalidate' of null**

Thank you.

Comment: if you remove the plugins the code works?

Comment: yes, it works but other jquery codes doesn't work.